# validateDOMNesting(...): <li> cannot appear as a descendant of <li>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting the warning message validateDOMNesting(...): cannot descendant of li
in the console and it shows the error is on the treeview and the timeline I dont know where to fix the code, the below code is facing that warning is there any solution for this?

```
 <Box>
    <TreeView  >
      <Timeline key={comment.id}>
        <TimelineItem>
          <TimelineSeparator>
            <Avatar  {...stringAvatar(comment.username) }  />{" "}
            <TimelineConnector />
          </TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineOppositeContent style={{maxWidth: "1px",paddingLeft: "0px",paddingRight: "0px", }}/>
          <TimelineContent>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
              <Typography variant="h6" sx={{fontSize:"15px" ,fontWeight:"bold"}}>
                {comment.username.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + comment.username.slice(1)}
              </Typography>
              <Item variant="span" sx={{fontSize:"10px"}}> {createdAt}</Item>
            </Stack>
     
  <ReactMarkdown   children={comment.body} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} />

           
            <TreeItem 
              nodeId="1" label={
              <TimelineContent>
               {canReply && (<Chip label="Reply"  onClick={() =>  setActiveComment({  id: comment.id,  type: "replying",  }) } 
               sx={{fontSize:"10px",mb:1}} size="small" icon={<ReplyIcon /> }/>  )}
                    {isReplying && ( 
                    <CommentForm submitLabel="Reply" hasCancelButton handleSubmit={(text) => addComment(text, replyId)} handleCancel={() => { setActiveComment(null);}} />)} 
                </TimelineContent> } >
              <TreeItem 
                nodeId="2"
                label={
                  <Timeline>
                    {replies.length > 0 && (
                      <div>
                        {replies.map((reply) => (
                          <Comment
                            comment={reply}
                            key={reply.id}
                            setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
                            activeComment={activeComment}
                            addComment={addComment}
                            parentId={comment.id}
                            replies={[]}
                            currentUserId={currentUserId}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Timeline>}/>
            </TreeItem>
          </TimelineContent>
        </TimelineItem>
      </Timeline>
    </TreeView>
  </Box>
```

Comment: You should post the code/component where you are using the <li> tag. This type of error basically happens when your resulting code contains elements something like this `<li><li></li></li>`

Comment: You'll have to narrow it down further. The error message is pretty clear as to the issue, so you'll have to find where exactly that `<li>` nesting is occurring

Comment: Actually i used only material ui there is no html tag i used in the component

Comment: This problem can be solved by adding <ul> tag between the inside nested <li> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're seeing, " `<li>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<li>`," occurs in HTML when you have a nested list structure (unordered or ordered lists) and mistakenly place one `<li>` element directly inside another `<li>` element, which is not allowed in HTML.

Here's an example of what's not allowed:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <li>Subitem 1</li> <!-- This is not allowed -->
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

To fix this issue, you should place nested lists (or subitems) inside their own parent `<ul>` (unordered list) or `<ol>` (ordered list) elements, like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

In the corrected code, the nested list is properly enclosed within its own `<ul>` element. This structure adheres to the HTML specifications and allows for well-structured and valid HTML.